# Chrome is crashing automatically when i was open the Chrome browser in Android Emulator Why?

Tags: java, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, android-emulator, appium

I want to test web application in Chrome browser on Android Emulator. It is Possible or not.

If it is Possible then how can i install Chrome browser. I already Installed Chrome browser in Android emulator but it is crashing automatically when i was open the Chrome browser in Android Emulator Why?

**Is there any way to create AVD which have Google Chrome browser as default?**

Comment: That is an issue with your emulator or the Android ROM you are using on the emulator. I would recommend you to clean Chrome's cache and data and see if that works (you can do that inside android's app configuration).

Comment: I already tried that but still i have that problem. I want to know now This problem have solved solution or not only ?

Comment: Have you tried other emulator? One that is not provided by Google? There is no way to know if this problem has a solution or not, because it's too generic. It can happen for a thowsand reasons.

Comment: Thanks MBarni ,                                                                                                                                                                      I also tried in Genymotion Emulator. That also have same problem. I want to konw Is there any way to create AVD which have Google Chrome browser as default?